# DEP6720: Failed to deploy package 'Native Debugger'

Tags: visual-studio, hololens

After updating the OS of the Hololens, I got the following error for all applications (built with Unity)

> DEP6720 Failed to deploy package 'native Debugger' 
>   DEP6859 Error
>   removing the file from the remote device DiagnosticsHubMsg.ddl not
>   found HRESULT exception 0x800700002

I googled and could not find any reference to this problem. I wonder if I have to update visual studio? (the latest seems to be 15.7.5)

EDIT:
I updated visual studio to 15.7.5 hoping to solve the problem. Now it is worse
I got the error but also these other errors

> DEP6721  Failed to deploy optional package 'XAML UI Debugger
>   2'DEP6950: Error transferring the file to the remote device
>   XamlDiagnostics DEP6721: Failed to deploy optional package 'XAML UI
>   Debugger Dependency' DEP6950: Error transferring the file to the
>   remote device: XamlDiagnostics.dll. Remote Device Disconnected'.
>   DEP6721: Failed to deploy optional package 'Standard Collector
>   Bridge'DEP6950: Error transferring the file to the remote
>   device:DiagnosticsHub.StandardCollector.Bridge.dll. Remote Device
>   Disconnected'. DEP6720: Failed to deploy package 'Windows 10 Remote
>   Tools' DEP6950: Error transferring the file to the remote
>   device:TailoredDeploy.exe. Remote Device Disconnected'. DEP6720:
>   Failed to deploy package 'Core CLR' DEP6950: Error transferring the
>   file to the remote device: clrcompression.dll. Remote Device
>   Disconnected'.

I am lost at what to do

Answer (score 0):

I could finally got to deploy on the hololens. 
After following different advice that did not work, in the end I *repaired* my installation of Visual Studio.

After the repair, VS was set again to the language of Windows. The colors of the editor also changed. I could deploy to the hololens there. (it took a lot of time the first time)

*However* -and for some strange reason- I **could not change my settings** back to english. If I do that, the same problem reappears. So even though I am more confortable with english, now I have to use visual studio in the same language of the operation system